# Incorrect variable declaration in some browsers

Tags: javascript

I declare the internal variables of the class in this way:

```
class Modulo {

    id; pasta; titulo; icone; css; js; linha;  

}
```

this works on chrome and Firefox desktop but fails on Edge and Safari
in browsers where there is an error, the following error is returned?

Edge: SCRIPT1005: SCRIPT1005: Expected '('

Safari: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uh, a class doesn't have "internal variables".

Comment: This syntax is _experiential_ and not all browsers support it (as you can see).  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations

Comment: What exactly do you expect this code to do? If you show us some more code that would use these "variables", we might be able to help you with how to declare/initialise them in a standard-conforming way.

Comment: @Bergi this synax is new, and still experiential (and not approved yet).  So, it's "valid," just unsupported.

Comment: As you noticed, not all browsers support this new syntax (where did you learn this?) as seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, it's not yet standard, even if some browsers already support it. However, I doubt that the OP even meant to use class fields, because if he did, you probably would know the proper terminology and that it's experimental.